# How to check ValidationResults on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, validation, validationrule

I have the a bunch of textboxes all with data validation as follows:

xaml

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:Validation2/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

c#

```
public class Validation2 : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        double result;
        return double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result) == true ? new ValidationResult(true, null) : new ValidationResult(false, "error");
    }
}
```

This works nicely, whenever I put anything but a number in the textboxes an error pops up. Now I have a button to send the "form", I'd like the button to check if there were any validation errors before doing anything. How would I go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation occurs before applying new value to source property. In your case - when you change property. In `wpf` there are also few [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) cases, but there is no `OnFormClosing` or similar. It's by design: control property may be bound to other control property (or several controls bound to *same* property), so validation occurs at latest when you change focus.

If you don't have cross-bindings, one property is bound to only one control, then you may utilize `UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit` - call `UpdateSource()` for each binding when form is about to be closed.

Other solution would be to don't display errors as *popups*. Error status could be a red border or `!` icon near.

I myself don't use validation mechanism at all. Instead, I have self-validating controls, to example, `TextBox` with property `IsDouble` to enable automatic validation for `double` values and property `GetDouble`, to parse value. I like more to validate everything at the end, while displaying actual status if validation will be ok or not to the user (red border, flashing caption, etc. **per control**).

Comment: I geuss using the word form was a bad idea. Basically I have a window with a bunch of textboxes and a button that creates an XML file of all the data entered. I want the button to not create a file if there are any validation errors.